# How do I run this javascript code to validate my form in my html doc?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head></head>
<body>
<script>
            function validateForm (){
                var formPi = 0
                var formPi = document.forms["Personal Information"]["firstname"].value;
                if(formPi == null ){
                    alert("Please fill out your First Name!");
                    return false;
                }

            }
</script>
<form name="Personal Information" action="" >
          <fieldset>
            <legend>Personal information:</legend>
            <br>
            First name:<br>
            <input type="text" name="firstname" value="" >
            <br>
            Last name:<br>
            <input type="text" name="lastname" value="" >
            <br>
            Email Address:<br>
            <input type="text" name="Email Address" value="" >
            <br>
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
            <!-- The for is meant to be validated once the subit button has been clicked-->
          </fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="demo_form.asp" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="fname" required>
```

```
   </form>      
  <p>If you click submit, without filling out the text field,
  your browser will display an error message.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

U can use `required` label for validations in each `input tag`

Answer (score 0):

add the onsubmit attribute to form tag

```
onsubmit="return validateForm();"
```

Update function validateForm to return true or false based on whether validation succeeds or fails. For more information see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit

Comment: Thanks. I thought my function was okay. They only problem is that it is not bringing up the pop-up box to print the statement I've put in.

Answer (score 0):

*Move* the `onsubmit="return validateForm()"` from your `submit` button to the `form` element, where it belongs. You also may change it to `return validateForm(this)`:

```
<form name="Personal Information" action="" onsubmit="return validateForm(this)" >
```

Your javascript function is almost ok, just add a `return true;` at the end, get the form from the `this` parameter we've added above and change the if condition:

```
function validateForm (form) {
    var formPi = form["firstname"].value;

    if (formPi == null || formPi == "") { // <-- condition changed
        alert("Please fill out your First Name!");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
 }
```

[Form demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2j7axomc/)